# JS file not working in angular but working in normal HTML,CSS+JS

Tags: javascript, html, angular

Bascially I am trying to create a dropdown like this.But the problem is: nothing is happening on clicking the dropdown button in angular whereas its working fine without using angular as in image.
Although I tried to run the JS file in angular just using alert("Hello World") which gave an alert to the webpage. This means JS file is correctly linked but this code isn't working in angular somehow. Help me please in trouble shooting this!

```js
var dropdown = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-btn");
    var i;

    for (i = 0; i < dropdown.length; i++) {
        dropdown[i].addEventListener("click", function () {
            var dropdownContent = this.nextElementSibling;
            if (dropdownContent.style.display === "block") {
                dropdownContent.style.display = "none";
            } else {
                dropdownContent.style.display = "block";
            }
        });
    }
```

```css
.tabs{
    position: absolute;
    top: 280px;
    width: 100%;
}

.dropdown-btn{
    text-decoration: none;
    border: none;
    background: none;
    display: block;

    padding-left: 53px;
    font-family: Work Sans;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 24px;
    line-height: 28px;
    letter-spacing: -0.02em;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #F8F7F3;
}

.dropdown-container{
    text-decoration: none;


    padding-left: 63px;
    display: none;
    background-color:#20737A;
    width: 100%;
    margin: auto;
}


.dropdown-container a{
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 18px;

}
```

```html
<div class="sidenav">
    <div class="items" id="item-0"><a href="#">The Senior Survey</a></div>
    <div class="tabs">
        <button class="items dropdown-btn">ACADEMICS</button>
        <div class="dropdown-container">
            <a href="#" id="comp-1">Department</a>
            <a href="#" id="comp-2">CPI</a>
        </div>
```

Comment: Why not do this the angular way? Directly manipulating the DOM like this doesn’t work very well in an Angular app.

Answer (score 0):

DOM manipulation through vanilla JS doesn't work in Angular.

You need to do it the Angular way.

In the HTML you add a `click` method which toggles the dropdown. And use the same variable in the dropdown container to show/hide using `*ngIf`.

```
<div class="sidenav">
    <div class="items" id="item-0"><a href="#">The Senior Survey</a></div>
    <div class="tabs">
        <button class="items dropdown-btn" (click)="showDropdown=!showDropdown">ACADEMICS</button>
        <div class="dropdown-container" *ngIf="showDropdown">
            <a href="#" id="comp-1">Department</a>
            <a href="#" id="comp-2">CPI</a>
        </div>
```

Add this variable `showDropdown` in your *Component*

```
@Component({...})
export class YourComponent {
  showDropdown:boolean = false;
}
```